# Can I export data from Salesforce to SQL in realtime?

Tags: data-export

I have recently started a new role where we have our outbound dialler integrated with Salesforce.

I have not worked with Salesforce before and would like to know if it possible to send data of the completed outbound records to a SQL database as soon as that record has been finished in Salesforce?

Thanks